# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0 Unsupported operation

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hey guys so I just began really practicing with the graphics portion of Java, and I have come into an error I have have never ever seen.

I'm going to post my code and then images of the error message is prompts me with, because I have not the least idea of what is actually happening, I have an idea but don't what to get myself confused so I figured maybe someone here has had a similar issue? Thanks guys! (developing in netbeans)

Program runs and throws this error when trying to click either button, error message line refers to line number of override method included in code

[image]

***the override method is auto generated after I run the program***
***It throws the error (image above) and error when trying to click either of the 2 buttons***

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author Jonathan
 */
class WindowDestroyer extends WindowAdapter
{
    public void window(WindowEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package game;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Set;



/**
 *
 * @author Jonathan
 */
public class ButtonDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 300;
    public ButtonDemo()
    {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        WindowDestroyer listener = new WindowDestroyer();
        addWindowListener(listener);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);

        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton sunnyButton = new JButton("Sunny");
        sunnyButton.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(sunnyButton);


        JButton cloudyButton = new JButton("Cloudy");
        cloudyButton.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(cloudyButton);
    }
    public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        if(actionCommand.equals("Sunny"))
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        else if(actionCommand.equals("Cloudy"))
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        else
            System.out.println("Error in button interface");

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question and set a better title

Comment: Look at the `actionPerformed` method, see where it says *"throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");"* - that would be your problem

Comment: What exactly am I doing that's not supported?

Comment: Nothing, but the code is generated to remind you that you should do something about this method.  Remove the `throw new ...` from the `ActionPerformed` method and it will work ... do nothing, but at least it won't throw an exception. Suggesting, don't use the form editor until you understand how the API is actual works

Answer (score 1):

The method you're wanting it to invoke has been misnamed. It auto-generated

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
```

because you declared:

```
public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e)
```

Not sure what "Preformed" means. :-)

The auto-generated actionPerformed just throws the exception you mentioned.

Comment: You're amazing, thank you!!!!!! I would have looked over that all night.

Comment: You're not alone. I often find myself catching Excpetions.

Comment: @DavidGreen, `I would have looked over that all night.` - when you override a method you should use `@Override` before the method signature and the compiler will notify you when you have an incorrect method signature. Notice how the generated code has the @Override? Also, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.